# Can't process quickfix messages written in file

Tags: quickfix

In my C++ QuickFix application, I am recording all MarketDataIncrementalRefresh messages i am getting into a file. This is being done using the following code:

```
void Application::onMessage(const FIX44::MarketDataIncrementalRefresh& message, const FIX::SessionID&)
{
   ofstream myfile("tapedol.txt", std::ios::app);
   myfile << message << endl << endl;
}
```

This part's working just fine. The problem occurs when I try to load the message later on.

```
FIX::Message msg
ifstream myfile("tapedol.txt");
getline(myfile,aux);
msg = aux;
msg.getField(55);
```

The program crashes every time it executes the last line. I suspect the problem is at the assignment to msg, but i'm not sure. If it is, what is the correct way to do such assignment? If not, how can I process the data within tapedol.txt, so that a message of type MarketDataIncremental refresh would be generated for each string in the file?

Comment: Why did you edit my post, @Jordan?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not complete enough to provide a full answer, but I do see one red flag:

```
msg.getField(55);
```

The Symbol field is not a top-level field of MarketDataIncrementalRefresh (it's inside the NoMDEntries repeating group), so this line will fail.  I think it would raise a FieldNotFound exception.

My C++ is rusty, but you should be able to catch an exception or something that should tell you exactly what line is erroring out.  Barring that, you need to open up a debugger.  Just saying "it crashed" means you quit looking too soon.

Comment: It is a top-level field in the data dictionary that my counterparty uses - in fact, i use getField(55) in my onMessage for MarketDataIncrementalRefresh. I've tried getting other fields also, but it didn't work either. I've tried using try catch to handle exceptions, but the program crashed before it could print out anything.